# Cardinality of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have seen the theorem about the cardinality of orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space. I wonder if we have a Hilbert space $H$ with an orthonormal basis having cardinality of the continuum, then what is the cardinality of $H$?

Answer (score 3):

Then the cardinality is also $\mathfrak{c}$. To see this, note that every element may be written as $\sum_{i\in I}a_i e_i$ where $a_i$ are complex numbers such that at most countably many of them are non-zero and $e_i$ are elements of a fixed orthonormal basis.

Then $|H|\leqslant \mathfrak{c}\cdot \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}$. On the other hand, it is clear that $H$ has cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$.

This may be generalised as follows. Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space of density character at most continuumm, then $X$ has cardinality continuum. Indeed, pick a dense set $D\subset X$ that has cardinality at most continuum. Now every element is a limit of sequence in $D$, so $|X|\leqslant |D|^{\aleph_0} \leqslant \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Why is it not $\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c}$? The cardinality of $A\times A$ is $|A|^2$, yes?

Comment: @jdods, I have added more details.

Comment: It just seems like a space with uncountably infinite dimension where each coordinate takes values in $\mathbb{C}$ is similar in structure to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}=\prod_{r\in\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}$. So it's cardinality is like uncountable infinity to the uncountable infinity power.

Comment: @jdods, but only countably many of the coordanates are possibly non-zero so it is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ consisting of functions which are non-zero only on a countable set.

Comment: Ah. I missed that detail! Thanks for helping!